# How can I add a scrollbar to a code block?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-block, horizontal-scroll-bar

How can I add a scrollbar to a code block when the code has long lines? For an example, look at the code block of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266641/richcontextmenu-display-after-rerender-oncontextmenu/13273579).

Comment: A scrollbar is added automatically when the length of any line in the code block exceeds the width of the block. One was added in [this answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134725/23897), for instance.

Comment: Except on mobile, which wraps long lines.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Oh i got it now. But when I created a block using "`>`" it doesn't add a scrollbar. Am I correct?

Comment: That is not a code block. That is a blockquote. Those are different things.

Comment: see: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/165773) "What do I need to do so that my code shows up properly..."

Comment: @gnat : Thanks, your comment is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters on your question said, this happens automatically. There are however some scripts available on [StackApps](http://www.stackapps.com) which improve the usability of the code blocks in general:

- [Click to expand code regions](https://stackapps.com/questions/2574/click-to-expand-code-regions)
- [Select Code Block Buttons Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2553/select-code-block-buttons-script)